# postgres can't find CSV file using copy command, inside python script - mac

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, copy

I get this error when attempting to python code:

```
COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.
```

I'm running postgres via docker on a mac, and using a virtual environment

I understand that this is happening because postgres doesn't have access to the file. However i've gone and given the file and all containing folders read permissions on the postgres user, but that still doesn't work. I can't use psql \copy in my code as I'm guessing this is something that can't be run in python. I've also tried placing my CSV into TMP folders but that hasn't worked either.

Are there any work arounds? I don't understand why the COPY command exists if it can't read any files, seems really pointless. I've seen this question a few times on stack overflow but have yet to find a single answer that works

Unless this is a Mac specific issue?

````
sql = '''
COPY maori.crime_data
FROM '/Users/myusr/Desktop/crime_data/AEG_Full_Data_data.csv' --input full file path here. see line 46
DELIMITER ',' CSV;
''' ```
````

I can't find anyway to  give postgres access to this file, no matter where I place it.

Comment: Assuming you are using `psycopg2` see [Copy From](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from).

Comment: Thank you @AdrianKlaver i'll look into this. Is there no way at all to get the above one working? Or is it common practice to use psycopg2 COPY FROM?

Comment: Yes, you could use `COPY .. FROM ..`. But the database server must have access and permissions to this file to read it. Usually not the best solution. `COPY ... FROM STDIN ...` is most likely a better solution, that's also what psycopg2 is using.

Comment: It makes life simpler. Also I suspect you are getting hit by, from this [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html),: *...and the name must be specified from the viewpoint of the server*. In other words the Postgres server in the Docker container cannot 'see' `/Users/myusr/Desktop/crime_data/`.

Comment: If the database is in a container, Docker prevents it from seeing any files that are on the host.  As far as the database container can tell the `/Users/myusr/...` path doesn't exist.  `COPY` would be more useful if the database wasn't running in an isolated filesystem, maybe installing it via Homebrew or a similar tool.